# Vaadin 8 + Spring Boot -- Server Connection lost, trying to reconnect

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-security, vaadin

For legacy reasons, I am required to use Vaadin `8.6.3`.

I have a simple index page with a menubar with three items (`home`, `user`, `admin`) and a welcome message.

I map that index page to `/` and want it to be accessible to non-authenticated users. the `home` menu option links to this page.

`user` and `admin` link to pages that do not yet exist but should be protected by Spring boot.

This is my (only, for now) WebSecurity configuration:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class AnyRequestConfiguration : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter(){

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .csrf().disable() //vaadin has its own csrf protection, therefore this must be disabled
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
    }

    override fun configure(web: WebSecurity){
        web
            .ignoring().antMatchers(
                "/VAADIN/**",
                "/frontend/**",
                "/webjars/**",
                "/images/**",
                "/frontend-es5/**", "/frontend-es6/**"
            )
    }
}
```

The page gets rendered, the menu and the welcome message displayed, but the connection is immediately lost and I get a

> Server connection lost, trying to reconnect

message in the upper right corner of the page with a spinning loading circle.

Why? How do I get this to work?

Index page:

```
import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringUI
import com.vaadin.ui.Label
import com.vaadin.ui.MenuBar
import com.vaadin.ui.UI
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout

@SpringUI(path = "/")
@Theme("mytheme")
class Index : UI() {
    companion object {
        const val HOME_MENU = "Home"
        const val USER_MENU = "User"
        const val ADMIN_MENU = "Admin"
        lateinit var navigation: MenuBar
            private set
    }
    private lateinit var layout: VerticalLayout

    override fun init(request: VaadinRequest?) {
        layout = VerticalLayout()

        //navigation bar
        navigation = MenuBar()
        navigation.id = "menubar"
        navigation.addItem(HOME_MENU)
        navigation.addItem(USER_MENU)
        navigation.addItem(ADMIN_MENU)

        //TODO: add onClick-listeners

        //welcome message
        val welcomeMessage = Label()
        welcomeMessage.id = "label.welcome"
        welcomeMessage.value = "Welcome to Spring Security Demo with Vaadin"


        layout.addComponents(
                navigation,
                welcomeMessage
        )

        this.content = layout
    }
}
```

**Update**

Devconsole shows error

> com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet-0.js:6129 POST http://localhost:8080/vaadinServlet/UIDL/?v-uiId=0 403

followed by warning

> com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet-0.js:6421 Wed May 08 12:19:17 GMT+200 2019 com.vaadin.client.communication.DefaultConnectionStateHandler
>   WARNING: Server returned 403 for xhr

after which it makes another attempt

> Wed May 08 12:20:33 GMT+200 2019 com.vaadin.client.communication.DefaultConnectionStateHandler
>
> INFO: Reconnect attempt 49 for XHR
>
> com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet-0.js:6421 Wed May 08 12:20:38 GMT+200 2019 com.vaadin.client.communication.DefaultConnectionStateHandler
>
> INFO: Re-sending last message to the server...
>
> com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet-0.js:6421 Wed May 08 12:20:38 GMT+200 2019 com.vaadin.client.communication.XhrConnection
>
> INFO: Sending xhr message to server: {"csrfToken":"24cb59a1-cd65-4774-b208-c7272314e8a7","rpc":[["0","com.vaadin.shared.ui.ui.UIServerRpc","resize",[1478,698,1478,698]]],"syncId":0,"clientId":0,"wsver":"8.6.3"}

Which also fails, so the circle repeats itself.

Comment: Any HTTP 403 in the browser developer tools console/network tabs?

Comment: @Tazavoo yes, actually (see edit).

Comment: Have you added explicitly or implicitly the `vaadin-client-compiled` dependency?

Comment: @cfrick As far as Vaadin dependencies go, I've added the respective Spring Boot Starter, as well as the Vaadin4Spring boot and security extensions. Not sure if either of them contains the client-compiled dependency. Will be able to check in half an hour, give or take. Unless you already know?

Comment: I believe the issue is that Vaadin's communication requests are still blocked.

These include the POST request to /vaadinServlet/UIDL/?v-uild=0.

You can add a requestMatcher that checks the URL and that the query parameter key is, for example, v-uild.

Comment: @Tazavoo of course you are right (403, not 404)

Comment: @User1291 You are following the wrong tutorial down the lines.  You are using V8, but your security settings contain `frontend-es5`, which is vaadin10.  You have to follow the settings for V8 as documented vaadin4spring.

Comment: How are you building and running? Try: build: mvn package -Dvaadin.productionMode run: mvn spring-boot:run -Dvaadin.productionMode

Comment: The csrf().disable() is the key to my setup not getting this error.  I'm running the latest spring security so without your full project I can't help.